# Python break statement not function

Tags: python, break

I am a beginner at python and have been stuck on a line of code for a while now and am unsure how to fix it.

The program requests user input, a HEX value and then converts this to a RGB value. I perform error checking to ensure that the input is a HEX value. However, when I input FEE**Z**00 it doesn't recognize that the char 'Z' is not in the string hexChars. (this should result in the break statement being activated)

I would greatly appreciate some help (please don't give me the full answer, I would like to learn)
Thank you!

```
hexChars = '0123456789ABCDEF'

rgb1 = (input("Enter 1st color: #")).upper()
rgb2 = (input("Enter 2nd color: #")).upper() 

if(len(rgb1) != 6 and len(rgb2) != 6): 
    print("Not a valid input!", end = "\n\n") 
    break

for i in range(6): 
    if((rgb1[i] not in hexChars) and (rgb2[i] not in hexChars)):
        print("Not a valid input!", end = "\n\n") 
        break
```

My input:

```
Enter 1st color: #feez00
Enter 2nd color: #feed00
```

Edit: Clarification is needed. As this is a beginner course we are not allowed to use functions or imports.

Comment: when i try running this with your inputs, I get an error on the first `break` that you can't do a break outside a loop. What are you trying to accomplish with that first break?

Comment: @scotscotmcc This is because I have everything encapsulated by a while loop.

Comment: The `while` loop needs to be part of your [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` is not allowed outside of a loop. In your example, you're using it in an `if` statement, which should throw an error (so I'm not sure how your code is running at all).

As an alternative, try keeping track of whether the input is valid in a local variable, called `is_valid`. You can update it to be `False` when you find something wrong with the input.

```py
hexChars = '0123456789ABCDEF'

rgb1 = (input("Enter 1st color: #")).upper()
rgb2 = (input("Enter 2nd color: #")).upper() 

is_valid = True

if(len(rgb1) != 6 or len(rgb2) != 6):  # as others noted, use or here
    is_valid = False
for i in range(6): 
    if((rgb1[i] not in hexChars) or (rgb2[i] not in hexChars)):
        is_valid = False

if not is_valid:
    print("Not a valid input!", end = "\n\n")
```

Comment: Thank you this is a similar solution I used. I modified it slightly as we are not allowed to use any functions or imports (beginner python).

Comment: Ah, not even functions! I'll edit my answer in that case

Comment: Thank you apologies for the lack of clarity

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with `re` module:

```py
>>> import re
>>> HEX = re.compile(r'(?:[\dA-F]){6}')
>>> bool(HEX.match('FEEA00'))
True
>>> bool(HEX.match('FEEZ00'))
False
```

Comment: While helpful; OP is a beginner and this isn't what they were asking for.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, this is not an applicable answer as we are supposed to not use any imports. (beginner python)

Comment: *"we are supposed to not use any imports"* - I don't see this in the question above, just saying.

Comment: @rv.kvetch apologies, thank you however for your help

Comment: by the principle of omission of crucial info, I would actually put this forth as an applicable answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `and` in the if-statement when checking for validity of the inputs.

The Loop reaches `i= 4`, then it checks `rgb1[i] not in hexChars`, which is `true` since `rgb[4] = z` and z is not in hexChars.
So far so good.

But now you are using `and (rgb2[i] is not in hexChars)`, which is `false`, since `rgb[4] = d` and d is in hexChars.

The `and`-condition checks if two statements are true. If one of them is false, it will return `false`.
That is why your if-statement basically looks like this `if(true and false)`, therefore not executing the code it contains
A quick fix would be using `or` instead.

Also `break` is only allowed in a loop, so you can not have it in the first if-statement

Answer (score -1):

Using `not in string/list` repeatedly is inefficient.

You should use `set` operations:

```
hexChars = set('0123456789ABCDEF')

def validate(s, size=6):
    return len(s) == size and hexChars >= set(s)

if not (validate(rgb1) and validate(rgb2)):
    # do something
```

If many inputs to validate:

```
if not all(map(validate, list_of_hex)):
    # do something
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was unclear in the description of my problem, as this is a beginner course we are not allowed to use and functions or imports. However, this will definitely be a useful answer for later in my course.

Comment: You don't have to use a function, the set operations are sufficient ;) But sure, I understand that you have limitations. Just keep in mind `x not in y` is expensive.